# How do I change an elements css properties in jquery if it is an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am currently try to change a css property of an element using jquery so that it will change once the page has loaded. For some reason though when trying to add either a css style or change its current property nothing happens?

What I am trying to achieve is the twitter feed at the bottom of this website:
http://www.footballkit.co.uk/

Here is my code:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

//Main Code Below:

<body>

<div id="dr">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dr").css("top","400px");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you kept the `position` as `absolute` in the `style.css` before you tried to change the `top`

Comment: You're also missing a `)` in your jQuery.

Comment: @RickHitchcock thanks for the quick response I have closed the parenthesis before and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @dvenkatsagar in my style.css it has absolute assigned to the "dr" id

Comment: Really? Because if you fix the problems we see in your code it works https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/srq1o4y7/

Comment: @j08691 sorry yes that did work position needed to be relative like you had done, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error, missing `);` at the end, always check your developer's console to check for javascript errors (f12 usually)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dr").css("top","400px");
}); //Syntax error missing );
```

Comment: That's only half the problem

Comment: I can make the website for him if you wish :), there are lot of problems going on, we can't  fix them all for him, he asked why the css properties didn't change, the syntax error is the problem.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande thanks haha only just started learning html etc so getting used to it, any idea how they did the twitter feed at the bottom of this website? www.footballkit.co.uk

Comment: I was just trying to be funny, not to be rude ;) Let me check that.

Comment: It's a div with position fixed, `#twitter { position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }`

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande its fine haha, and thanks for the help :)

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande  I think your answer is better than mine (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35024206/3176270). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error. That is not something important.

I made a demo for you on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey3cpffy/1/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#dr").css("top","400px");
    });
```

And if `top` is not working, you have to check your style. Element with **static** position can't get position (top, left, right, bottom)
[DEMO with style](https://jsfiddle.net/ey3cpffy/6/)